# Save State to Cookie with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, cookies, fonts

I currently have the following jQuery attached to a button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('#opendyslexic-toggler').click(function() {
var $styleSheet = jQuery('#opendyslexic');

 $styleSheet.prop('disabled') ?  $styleSheet.prop('disabled', false)  
                              : $styleSheet.prop('disabled', true);
});
</script>
```

What this script does is change the font on a website by enabling a stylesheet.  I would like to have this information saved to a cookie when a user clicks on the button (i.e., if the user clicks the button once, I would like the font changed [as currently happens] **and** have that choice saved to a cookie so it persists across parts of the site and across sessions, and, on a second click, I would like the cookie erased or the value changed so that the users decision to use the default font is similarly preserved, et cetera).

I have tried probably a half dozen different ways of doing this, but have thus far been unsuccessful in getting the cookie to save and to be read properly so that the font choice persists as intended.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you testing this locally or on an actual website? Cookies don't work in Chrome from localhost, so that's something to keep in mind.

Comment: I'm testing it on an live, public-facing test website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using localStorage instead, and with the shim for **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)** that falls back to cookies, it's pretty much cross browser:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    if ( localStorage.getItem('font') ) {
        $('#opendyslexic').prop('disabled', localStorage.getItem('font') == 'true');
    }

    $('#opendyslexic-toggler').on('click', function() {
         $('#opendyslexic').prop('disabled', function(_, prop) {
              localStorage.setItem('font', !prop);
              return !prop;
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  Here's my test page: http://zyniker13.com/open-dyslexic-test-page/.

Comment: @Zyniker - my bad, forgot about the string conversion in localStorage, edited the answer.

Comment: That seems to work.  If I wanted to toggle #opendyslexic and another stylesheet (e.g., #other-stylesheet), do you know how to change the code so that it would do both?  That would make it possible to eliminate that half-second or so of transition time as the page loads both the baseline CSS and then the additional OpenDyslexic CSS.